# Angular 8 Application running issues in IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular8

App is not starting in IE11 locally but works when deployed on azure.I have added all the polyfills required to run angular on ie 11, however i am getting this SCRIPT 5022 error when running the application on IE 11 locally. Please help me out in this.

[image]

[image: It's throwing an error in vendor.js]

Here is the polyfill.ts

```js
    (window as any).global = window;
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
(window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
(window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: Did you try to add  "target": "es5"  in tsconfig.json file? if not, I suggest you add it and again try to test the issue. You can also try to refer to the steps mentioned in this article that may help to fix this issue. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have tried this, didn't work...

Comment: did you install the necessary modules via NPM after uncommenting it in polyfill.ts file?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes I did.

Comment: Can you please inform us whether this is an empty project or it has some code in it? If you had added some code then did you check whether this issue can occur with newly created project or not? If not please check and let us know about it.